# How can I get the Display Page's Asset Entry in a Liferay Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, liferay-7.3

How can I get the Asset Entry in a Freemarker (a Fragment, Widget Template, Web Content Template, etc) inside a Display Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INFO_ITEM_DETAILS` object from `Request` global variable, to get the Asset `className` and `classPK`, and then recover your Display Page Asset with `AssetEntryLocalService`

```
<#assign assetEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.asset.kernel.service.AssetEntryLocalService")/>

<#if Request.INFO_ITEM_DETAILS??>
  <#assign 
    info_item_reference = Request.INFO_ITEM_DETAILS.getInfoItemReference()
    
    className = info_item_reference.getClassName()
    classPK = info_item_reference.getClassPK()
    
    asset = assetEntryLocalService.getEntry(className, classPK)
  />
  ${asset}
</#if>
```

> make sure to use Freemarker's [alternative (square bracket) syntax](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html)
>  when creating a Fragment